# Getting error on button click to fetch location

Tags: android, android-gps

The error I get is as follows

**Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference**

Please tell me where I'm going wrong

Activity onCreate function

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.partymb);
    textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menuact);
    locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationlistener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            textview.append("\n "+location.getLongitude() +" "+location.getLatitude());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.INTERNET
            },10);
            return;
        }
    } else {
        configureButton();
    }
}
```

onRequestPermissionResult function

```
public void onRequestPermissionResult(int requestCode, String[] permission, int[] grantResults) {
  switch (requestCode){
      case 10:
          if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
              configureButton();
          return;
  }
}
```

ConfigureButton function

```
private void configureButton() {
    mbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view) {
            locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 5, locationlistener);
        }
    });

}
```

I took reference from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNb_3QKSmMk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_menuact);
```

Above line should come immediately after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

And after that do `findViewById`.

You are finding views before setting a view so all views will be null only.

Answer (score 0):

you are setting view and id before

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_menuact);
```

you should set like below

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


setContentView(R.layout.activity_menuact);
  mbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.partymb);
    textview=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
 }
```